# What is the behavior of lifecycle deletes if a lifecycle event notification fails to publish to SNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns, lifecycle, s3-lifecycle-policy

If I setup Lifecycle event notifications on a bucket and a notification fails to publish to sns does it retry the notification request forever or does it drop the notification? (best effort vs guranteed delivery)

Also if it does retry forever, does that mean a lifecycle action (for example object expiration delete) is denied/blocked until after the notification is successfully published to sns or how does it work?

Is there a way for me to test this to confirm the bahvior?